# php code to loop through database

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

I am **beginner** using php and I have a postgres database containing the following table:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Phone_Number| User_ID| file_ID|  file_Path     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 123456789   | 12345  | abc123 | /picture_22.jpg|
--------------------------------------------------
| 987654321   | 67890  | xyz567 | /voice_33.mp3  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want to loop through every row, read the file_ID
append the it to the end of url, go to url get the result which is a download link, I am not sure how to achieve that. I appreciate any help/assistance.

P.S: Here is my incomplete code:

```
<?PHP
ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);

$website = "https://website.com;

//Connect to Database
$con = pg_connect( "postgres://................."  );

$query = "SELECT * FROM userdata";
$results = pg_query($con, $query);
$row_users = pg_fetch_array($results);

while ($row_users = pg_fetch_array($results)) {

    $fileID =    <---------------- Not sure what goes here
    $filePath = file_get_contents('$website/.getFile?file_id=.fileID');
    $fixedPath = str_replace("\\","","$filePath");

}

pg_close($con); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?PHP
ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);

$website = "https://website.com;

//Connect to Database
$con = pg_connect( "postgres://................."  );

$query = "SELECT * FROM userdata";
$results = pg_query($con, $query);
# NOT NEEDED You are losing a row here $row_users = pg_fetch_array($results);

while ($row_users = pg_fetch_array($results)) {

    $fileID =   $row_users['file_ID']; # This is what goes here
    $filePath = file_get_contents("$website/.getFile?file_id={$fileID}");
    $fixedPath = str_replace("\\","","$filePath");

}

pg_close($con); 
?>
```

In addition to marking the change that you need to make to get the file id, I have marked an small error in your code which results in your losing a row of data. And also in the use of your variable in the file_get_contents call.

Over here the use of pg_query is fine, but if you need to use parameters, please use [pg_query_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php).

Comment: Thank you for your help, when I run the code using XAMPP I get the following error:
**Call to undefined function pg_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\downloader.php on line 8**
Any hints on how to fix that please?

Comment: Yeah you don't have the extension involved http://php.net/manual/en/pgsql.installation.php (but this is really a different question)

Comment: I have successfully installed the extension, however, when I run the code, I get the following notice:
**Notice: Undefined index: file_ID in C:\wamp64\www\downloader.php**
It looks like either the _query_ or the part _pg_fetch_array($results)_ is causing this.

Comment: postgresql column names should be lowercase.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed that, but I have another issue: `$filePath` gets the following value: `{"ok":true,"result":{"file_id":"AwADBAADrAADmmT8BE_FGiduk6tZAg","file_size":106562,"file_path":"voice\/file_1.oga"}}`
I can't seem to access the last part to replace the backslash (i.e. `file_path":"voice\/file_1.oga`)

Comment: "another issue" at stackoverflow means another questtion

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with single quote

```
$fileID =   $row_users['file_ID'];
$filePath = file_get_contents($website."/getFile?file_id=".$fileID);
$fixedPath = str_replace("\\","",$filePath);
```

I think you have missed the "$" with the variable `$fileID`. Also statement  inside single quote is not processed by php interpreter so `$filePath` was not getting correct value

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be:

```
$fileID = $row_users['file_ID'];
$filePath = file_get_contents("$website/.getFile?file_id=$fileID");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
    ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);

    $website = "https://website.com;

    //Connect to Database
    $con = pg_connect( "postgres://................."  );

    $query = "SELECT * FROM userdata";
    $results = pg_query($con, $query);
    $row_users = pg_fetch_array($results);

     while ($row_users = pg_fetch_array($results)) {

        $fileID = $row_users["file_ID"];
        $filePath = file_get_contents("$website/getFile?file_id=" . $fileID);
        $fixedPath = str_replace("\\","","$filePath");

      }

     pg_close($con); 
?>
```